# Warming up of Cloud Service Web Role deployments before VIP Swap

Tags: iis, azure-cloud-services

**What is the correct way to way to warm up Cloud Service instances before performing a VIP Swap?**

We're running two Web Role instances in our cloud service, and have already performed the following optimizations:

- [IIS 8.0 Application Initialization module in a Windows Azure Web Role](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/iis-8-0-application-initialization-module-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/)
- [Controlling Application Pool Idle Timeouts in Windows Azure](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/controlling-application-pool-idle-timeouts-in-windows-azure)
- Set AutoStart = true

Despite all these changes our site still takes around 10-20 seconds to start up after having performed a VIP Swap.

Is doing something like using a [WebRole to hit the endpoints](http://weblogs.thinktecture.com/cweyer/2011/01/poor-mans-approach-to-application-pool-warm-up-for-iis-in-a-windows-azure-web-role.html) still the best way to go?